# understanding a proof about the set of nowhere differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, baire-category

> Show that the set of nowhere differentiable functions is residual in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.

It suffices to show its complement is first category. Below is part of a proof of this statement. In the proof below, it's not too hard to show that $A = \cup_{k,l} A_{k,l}$ and that each $A_{k,l}$ is closed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> The part I don't really understand is the claim "By our choice of $\omega$ we can choose $x\in [0,1]$ with $0<|x-a| < \frac{1}k$ such that ..." Why does this $x$ exist? I tried explicitly finding this $x$, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\frac{2\pi}\omega<\min\left\{\frac1k,\frac{r}{2(\ell+m)}\right\}$. Let $x_0=a-\frac{2\pi}\omega$ and $x_1=a+\frac{2\pi}\omega$. If $x_0<x<x_1$, then $0<|x-a|<\frac1k$, and $|x-a|<\frac{r}{2(\ell+m)}$. Moreover, $\sin\omega x_0=0=\sin\omega x_1$, so $\sin\omega x$ goes through at least one full cycle as $x$ ranges over $[x_0,x_1]$, and there must be points $x_2,x_3\in(x_0,x_1)$ such that $\sin\omega x_2=1$ and $\sin\omega x_3=-1$. Let $x=x_2$ if $\sin\omega a\le 0$, and let $x=x_3$ otherwise.